# Which team got the highest possession but still lost the match?

Tags: football, records

In the second round of 2017/18 Premier League season, Arsenal lost to Stoke City despite of [having 77% possession](http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/40908333). Does it set the record for the highest possession team losing the match? If not, which team is the record holder?

Comment: That's not a record. La Liga 33rd round [Granada 1 - 0 Barcelona](http://www.flashscore.com/match/bRtLL98a/#match-statistics;0), 19% against 81%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is the record holder, but lowest that I could find is [Celtic winning 2-1 against Barcelona](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/football/teams/celtic/9663926/Stats-How-Celtic-beat-Barcelona-despite-having-just-16-per-cent-possession.html) in Champions League with just [16.36% possession](https://www.theguardian.com/football/table/2012/nov/08/lowest-champions-league-possession-percentages-win) meaning Barcelona lost with **83.64% possession**.

And the match mentioned in question is not even the record for Premier League, that record belongs to [Burnley's 19.4% win against Liverpool](https://www.premierleague.com/news/77002) meaning Liverpool lost with **80.6% possession**. <sup>[(2)](https://www.thisisanfield.com/2016/08/burnley-record-lowest-possession-premier-league-win-since-records-began-liverpool/)</sup>